# How to obtain attribute as string from simplexml_load_file object correctly?

Tags: php, simplexml

Let me have XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <default href="index.txt"/>
</xml>
```

How to access "index.txt" value correctly?

I found it can be accessible by

```
$directory = simplexml_load_file("admin/content/directory.xml");
$defaulthref = strval($directory->default[0]['href']);
```

But is it possible to avoid `strval()` function usage?

Answer (score 2):

You can write an Xpath expression like this

```
default/@href/text()
```

or

```
default/@href/string()
```

Comment: I dont know PHP, but wherever you have to write xpath expression, you can use the above xpath expressions